# Ionic 2 Native File: Create directory recursively

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using Ionic 2 Cordova Plugin File to save some files in a Ionic Hybrid app. I would like to store them in directories, which, if not already existing, I try to create with:

```
this.file.createDir(this.getPathWithoutLast(absolutePath), this.getLastPathString(absolutePath), true);
```

My absolute path looks like this:

```
file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
```

I get the error {"code":1,"message":"NOT_FOUND_ERR"}.

After some testing, I think that the method cannot create directories recursively, so I implemented my own method for creating them one after the other.

However, this seems like something that more people need so I would like to ask if there really is no such option in the Plugin and if not, whether there is a reason I did not think of.

Thanks everyone for their time!
Pavol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to post my solution as well, just in case:

```js
    public async makeSureDirectoryExists(relDirPath: string): Promise<boolean> {
        console.log(`making sure rel Path: ${relDirPath}`);
        const absolutePath = this.file.dataDirectory + relDirPath;
        console.log(`making sure abs Path: ${absolutePath}`);
        const pathParts = relDirPath.split('/');

        const doesWholePathExist: boolean = await this.doesExist(absolutePath);
        if (doesWholePathExist) {
            return true;
        }
        let currentPath = this.file.dataDirectory;
        while (pathParts.length > 0) {
            const currentDir = pathParts.shift();
            const doesExist: boolean = await this.doesExist(currentPath + currentDir);
            if (!doesExist) {
                console.log(`creating: currentPath: ${currentPath} currentDir: ${currentDir}`);
                const dirEntry: DirectoryEntry = await this.file.createDir(currentPath, currentDir, false);
                if (!dirEntry) {
                    console.error('not created!');
                    return false;
                }
            }
            currentPath = currentPath + currentDir + '/';
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the doesExist method? Please add that code as well.

Comment: You can see the reference from [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#create-directories-). The `doesExist` method uses this functionality erroCallback to return Promise<boolean>. Sorry it was a long time ago I can't find the original code

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I had the same problem so ended writing my own function that will handle this.

Didn't test this one as I can't find the original one but it should be something like this

```
createRecursivePath(path: string | Array<string>): Promise<string> {

    if (typeof path === 'string') {
        path = path.split('/');
        return this.createRecursivePath(path);
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(path)) {
        return Promise.reject('Error on data entry');
    }
    let promiseArray: Array<Promise<DirectoryEntry>> = path.map((dirName, index, array) => {
        let createdDirPath = array.slice(0, index);
        return this.file.checkDir([this.getDefaultAppPath(), ...createdDirPath].join('/'), dirName)
            .then()
            .catch(() => this.file.createDir([this.getDefaultAppPath(), ...createdDirPath].join('/'), dirName,false));
    });

    return Promise.all(promiseArray)
        .then(() => Promise.resolve(Array.isArray(path) && path.join('/') || ''));
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, interesting that it is not implemented by the plugin, do you think a pull request would be wise?

Comment: I would guess that the ionic team probably had a reason not to implement this (maybe some safety feature). But go ahead and create one if you want?!? :)

Comment: @AlexanderSashaShcherbakov Sometimes this function returns an error and sometimes not. maybe the Promise.all issue with how it created in sequence.

Comment: reading this again, the promise.all might be wrong as it resolves in async so some paths might not exist and can't create nested folders. So resolving the promise array in sync will fix the issue